# && for null safe method invocation, good or bad?

Tags: javascript, jslint

Just started using jslint to check my javascript code.  It indicated I should be replacing

```
result = value ? value : defaultValue;
```

with

```
result = value || defaultValue;
```

I thought this was a nice shortcut, and tried applying the principle to method calls on potentially null variables, so instead of:

```
if (arg) {
    arg.doSomething();
}
```

I tried:

```
arg && arg.doSomething();
```

The latter works fine in the browser, but jslint complains with "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

Is the last statement bad, wrong, dangerous, or is jslint being overprotective ?  Using `var dummy = arg && arg.doSomething();` do get the message to go away just seems silly.

Comment: I thought Crockford called `&&` the "guard" and encouraged its use just like your example. Maybe he doesn't use jslint?

Comment: @RobG: He probably only uses the guard in expressions. :)

Comment: It's certainly not wrong; it's what Closure Compiler also does when minifying: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home. (Try minifying your `if` clause.)

Comment: @RobG: Douglas Crockford doesn't use JSLint, Douglas Crockford is JSLint. With apologies to Chuck Norris :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSLint should be considering this a warning at best (but then, JSLint doesn't differentiate warnings from outright errors), definitely not an error — but remember that JSLint is about enforcing Crockford's coding style standards, which may vary from yours (they certainly vary from *mine*); you might check out [JSHint](http://jshint.com) which offers more control, though I'm not immediately seeing an option for this specific condition.

Your `arg && arg.doSomething()` is fine, but be aware that it's somewhat advanced and you'll lose some people doing maintenance on your code. I never use it in that way. I do use it in expressions, but not on its own. Whether you use it is up to you, but it's not dangerous, just somewhat opaque.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not saying I don't use that pattern rarely, but I'd definately suggest to go with the `if( expr ) { }` for convinience.

Comment: Since you can even omit brackets for a single statement, `arg && arg.doSomething();` isn't that much shorter than `if(arg) arg.doSomething();`.

Comment: jslint complains about that too: Expected '{' and instead saw 'arg'.  It seems all if/while/etc constructs must wrap even single statements in {}.

Comment: @andypandy: Yes. Again, that's because JSLint enforces Crockford's style, and braces are not optional in his style although they are optional in the language. (I'm with him on that one, as it happens, but it's a style choice...)